# How can I tell if an infinite truth tree is valid?

Tags: logic

I read that truth trees are not the best way of searching for an interpretation because in some cases, the tree will always be infinite even when there **is** an interpretation (with a finite domain) that exists.

Why is it that truth trees can be infinite when there exists an interpretation with a finite domain? And how can I determine whether the sentences at the root of an infinite truth tree are valid or invalid, if creating a tree does not help me get closer to that goal?

An example of an infinite tree, taken from Bonevac's Deduction (pg 205 #50):

$$\forall x(Fx\to\exists y(Fy\land Ryx))\\
\exists x(Fx\land Rxx) $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are able to "see" that the application of the rules for generating the tree will produce a "rightmost" infinite descending path with :

> $Ra_0a_0, Ra_1a_0, Ra_2a_1 ...$.

This will happen because when you "instantiate" $∃x(Fx \land Rxx)$ with $a_0$ new, you have to apply the rule fo $\forall$ with $a_0$, and this step produce a new formula $∃x(Fx \land Rxa_0)$.

This in turn must be "instantiated" with $a_1$ new, and so on *ad infinitum*.

The infinite rightmost open branch will give us an interpretation satisfying the two formulae; the interpretation will be :

> domain $D = \{ a_0, a_1, a_2, ... \}$, $F$ holds for all $a_i$ and also $Ra_0a_0, Ra_1a_0, Ra_2a_1 ...$ hold.

But it is easy to verify that there is a "simpler" interpretation satisfying the formulae :

> domain $D = \{ a_0 \}$, $Fa_0$ and $Ra_0a_0$.

The "procedure" gives us an interpretation, it it exists; it does not necessarily gives us the "simplest".

*Note.*

The refutation tree method (or the tablaux method ) for *sentential logic* is complete, in the sense that if applied to a *tautology*, all the paths of the tree will close after a finite number of step.

If the tree is finished (and in sentential logic this will always happen after a finite number of steps) with some path that is not closed, the formula is satisfiable (and its negation isn’t a tautology).

You must take into account two features of sentential logic :

a) the refutation tree will always finish after a finite number of steps (because at each step the “complexity” of the formulae – in terms of occurrences of connectives - will decrease)

b) the truth-table device allows us to check in advance if a formula $A$ is a tautology or not.

If now we move to *first-order logic*, instead of tautology, we have the notion of *valid* formula.

We must note the first difference compared to sentential logic: in f-o logic the device of truth-tables will not work any more; in general, the number of combination to be tested is infinite.

Again, the refutation tree method (or the tablaux method ) for f-o logic is complete, in the sense that if applied to a valid formula, all the paths of the tree will close after a finite number of step.

But now, applying the method to a formula $A$ that is **not** valid (i.e. such that $\lnot A$ is *satisfiable*) we have that either the tree is finite and a path is open or there is a path that continues to infinity (an infinite path is open by definition; thus an *infinite* path does not "detect" a *valid* formula: if the path is open, there is an interpretation satisfying *all* formulae on the path, root included).

Again, you must remember that there are sentences (i.e.closed formulae) like $∃x∃y(\lnot x=y)$ that are not valid (because not satisfiable in an interpretation with only one object in the domain) and whose negation $∀x∀y(x=y)$ is not valid either (because not satisfiable in an interpretation with more than one object in the domain).

Taking into account that we cannot check in advance if $A$ or $\lnot A$ are valid or not, if we run the refutation method with a couple of formulae like the above, and if after a finite number of steps neither of the two trees is finished, we are not licensed to conclude anything (if the result is not "evident" with insight, as in your example; see also Bonevac, page 186-187).

This is the reason why the refutation method does not give us a solution to the problem about the *decidability* of f-o logic (which is *undecidable*).

Comment: Very thorough answer, thank you for taking the time to explain!